# Systemback Root User Permissions

Tags: systemback

I am in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and I installed the latest version of Systemback.

**Problem**

My issue is that on boot up  I get error messages stating that `the systemback scheduler daemon failed to start` and `failed to get root user permissions`.

**UPDATE**
update:

Did some more snooping... all ubuntu states that the systemback-scheduler is installed, in reality it is not installed:

```
#which systemback-scheduler
#
```

And

```
# locate systemback-scheduler
/usr/share/doc/systemback-scheduler
/usr/share/doc/systemback-scheduler/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/systemback-scheduler/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/systemback-scheduler
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemback-scheduler.prerm
```

The systemback systemd service files do not exist.   I tried purging systemback from my ubuntu and reinstalling, but same result.

Any hints on how to fix this?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem
locate this file:

locate sbschedule.desktop

it's in xdg folder, another one is sbscheduler-kde.desktop
I just deleted them.
done.

So it turns out this scheduler is auto start when desktop kicks in.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the instructions here: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-systemback-debian-ubuntu-linux-mint

You need to start it within a root account login or follow the steps as described there in the link above. set xhost, then switch to root user, set xdisplay and then launch systemback.

Comment: It seems that we are members of the same email newsletter.  I followed those instructions and doubled-checked multiple times..  I still get the above error

Comment: I can start and run systemback as root... but at boot I get permissions error and trying to launch as non-root I get a permissions error, where I should get a login/authentication option instead

Comment: @nightwatch this is where you need to learn how system permissions work.  Running something as root almost guarantees that you won't be able to run it as non-root without permissions errors.